# Passing nested list as an argument to a method

Tags: python, list, nested

Below code is working fine

```
class p:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log={
            'name':'',
            'id':'',
            'age':'',
            'grade':''
        }
           
    def parse(self,line):
        self.log['id']=line[0]
        self.log['name']=line[1]
        self.log['age']=line[2]
        self.log['grade']=line[3].replace('\n',"")
        
        return self.log


obj=p()
with open(r"C:\Users\sksar\Desktop\Azure DE\Datasets\dark.csv",'r') as fp:
    line=fp.read()
data=[i.split(',') for i in line.split('\n')]
for i in data:
    a=obj.parse(i)
    print(a)
```

Input:

```
1,jonas,23,A
2,martha,23,B
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'jonas', 'id': '1', 'age': '23', 'grade': 'A'}
{'name': 'martha', 'id': '2', 'age': '23', 'grade': 'B'}
```

Question is: When i make a method call(a=obj.parse(i)) out of the loop, inputs are overwritten and give below as o/p `{'name': 'martha', 'id': '2', 'age': '23', 'grade': 'B'}` simply missing the previous records.

How to make a method(parse) call without having to iterate through nested loop(Input data) and feed data to the method call? simply how to get the desired output without for loop...

Comment: As an aside, you could construct `data` with `with open(...dark.csv",'r') as fp: data=list(csv.reader(fp))` if you wanted to.

Comment: Is your desired result a sequence of dictionaries whose values are taken from each line of the csv file? And is your question how to make a sequence from another sequence without iterating?

Comment: Noo. I could have imported pandas and easly handled csv.
Here i'm just trying in a diff way without library, just for the sake of learning.
Inside the loop the method is being called multiple times and interupt the performance rit, my question is exactly how to call the method and print the output without executing multiple times inside the loop

Comment: have a look at this

```
with open(r"C:\Users\sksar\Desktop\Azure DE\Datasets\dark.csv",'r') as fp:
    line=fp.read()
data=[i.split(',') for i in line.split('\n')]
a=obj.parse(i)
print(a)
````
If i remove the loop and call the method once, single record(in a dictionary form) is returned in a place where two records are actually supposed to, as per the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont get why you are trying to avoid an explicit loop. I mean, even if you don't see it in your code, if there is something being iterated, there will be a loop somewhere, and if so, ["explicit is better than implicit"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python).

In any case, check this:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\sksar\Desktop\Azure DE\Datasets\dark.csv",'r') as fp:
  [print(obj.parse(x.split(','))) for x in fp.readlines()]
```